# What is the possible value for the subgroup of index 2?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H\leq G$ and $[G:H]\leq 2$. If the $|G|=n$ then $|H|=n$ if $n$ is odd. What is happening when  $n$ is even? What are the possible values for $|H|$ when $n$ is even?

Thanks.

Comment: For finite groups, $|H| [G:H] = |G|$.

Comment: $[G:H]=|G|/|H|\in\{1,2\}\iff |H|\in\{|G|,|G|/2\}$.

Comment: (@T.Bongers That equality holds with infinite cardinals too.)

Comment: @sea turtles This question came from projective plane, so $n$ is a prime power order of the plane. For even order want to know what is happening. I will try with your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $[G:H] \leq 2$ and $|G|=2k$ then $|H| = k$ or $|H| =2k$. If $|H|=k$ then $[G:H] = 2$ and H is a normal subgroup that contains every square. If $|H|=2k$ then $H=G$.